# Finding the index of an object in an array when there are multiple possibilities

Tags: php

I have an array, and I want to find all of the indexes of a certain object in the array. When I use `array_search`, it only returns the first index in which the object can be found.

```
echo array_search(3, array(3, 3, 4));
```

This returns 0, but I want to know that both indexes 0 and 1 have the integer 3 as their object. Is there a way of doing this without using a `for` loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try array_keys() method :

```
  $array = array(3, 3, 4);
  print_r(array_keys($array, "3"));
```

For reference:

array_keys() — Return all the keys or a subset of the keys of an array Info & usuage examples : http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php

Comment: Never knew about this secondary parameter

Comment: Is it possible to use `array_keys` to find the indexes of integers less than 4? `array_keys($array, < 4)`

Comment: Yep kinda, use array_intersect first:
$range = range(0,4);
$newarray = array_intersect($array, $range);
this will give you an array that you only has the values 4 or less. Although it assumes you dont have any negative values.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to array_keys, array_filter() retains associativity

```
$key = 3;
$array = array(1, 3, 3, 4, 3, 5);

$result = array_filter(
    $array,
    function ($item) use ($key) {
        return ($item == $key);
    }
);

var_dump($result);
```